# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is the Winforms C# code:

```
dateTimePicker3.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker3.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
dateTimePicker4.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker4.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";

string connectionstring = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ExpenseManagerDB;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
sqlconn.Open();

string query = @"sp_Total";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@date1", dateTimePicker3.Value);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date2", dateTimePicker4.Value);

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Stored procedure follows:

```
Alter PROCEDURE sp_Total @date1 date,@date2 date

AS
BEGIN

Select SUM(Price) from EntryDetails where Name = 'Sreejith' and Date between '@date1' and '@date2'
Select SUM(Price) from EntryDetails where Name = 'Siva' and Date between '@date1' and '@date2'
Select SUM(Price) from EntryDetails where Name = 'Pavithran' and Date between '@date1' and '@date2'
Select SUM(Price) from EntryDetails where Name = 'Nithin' and Date between '@date1' and '@date2'

END
GO
```

I'm getting this error 
**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string**

Comment: Side note - [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures."

Answer (score 1):

it is not winforms, it is sql error

'@date1' and '@date2' are not dates but strings

remove '' in stored procedure

```
Alter PROCEDURE sp_Total @date1 date,@date2 date

AS
BEGIN
Select SUM(Price) from EntryDetails where Name = 'Sreejith' and Date between @date1 and @date2
Select SUM(Price) from EntryDetails where Name = 'Siva' and Date between @date1 and @date2
Select SUM(Price) from EntryDetails where Name = 'Pavithran' and Date between @date1 and @date2
Select SUM(Price) from EntryDetails where Name = 'Nithin' and Date between @date1 and @date2
END
```

UPDATE

```
Alter PROCEDURE sp_Total @date1 date, @date2 date

AS
BEGIN
  Select Name, SUM(Price) as SumPrice
  from EntryDetails 
  where 
    (Date between @date1 and @date2)
    and Name in ('Sreejith','Siva','Pavithran','Nithin')
  group by Name
END
```

Comment: Then how could i pass @date1 and date2 from my form

Comment: you can pass them because you declared stored procedure with parameters @date1 date,@date2 date. that's correct. but then you don't use them and compare Date field with strings '@date1' and '@date2'

Comment: but i want data for only selected dates ie i have compare

Comment: Please edit in my stored procedure to get data for particular dates

Comment: if it is working, accept answer, please. about your next query: execute stored procedure in sql-server with the same parameters #date1and #date2 and you will see 4 results. i suppose you take only 1st result in your form. can't say more because you didn't show that code

Comment: there are four select statement queries in sp but only first one is giving result

Comment: execute stored procedure in sql-server with the same parameters #date1and #date2 and you will see 4 results. thay can have numeric value or be empty (0 rows) but stored procedure will process and return 4 select

Comment: still i 'm getting 1 result ie first select statement

Comment: I will tell my req: i want total price for individual 4 persons between those dates. I will be selecting the dates from datepicker in winforms. Currently it is giving only first person ie first query result in sp. Please help me to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `@date1` and `@date2` as `Date` types to the procedure, because the procedure takes in 2 params of type `Date`.

Hence in your code, you can change something as below:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date1", dateTimePicker3.Value.Date);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date2", dateTimePicker4.Value.Date);
```

Try it, let us know if you face any further problems.